# Getting spaces in file while redirecting db2 select query output to a file in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, db2, sh

Shell script contains the code:

```
db2 -x "select trim(file_path || '/' || filename) from mytable" > $my_temp_file
```

output in file:

```
/path1/file1.txt


/path2/file2.txt


/path3/file3.txt


/path4/file4.txt
```

Even if i am using the

```
command: sed -i '/^$/d' $my_temp_file
```

OR

```
command: awk 'NF' $my_temp_file
```

after the db2 command within the script, that's NOT working...

Why these spaces are coming and WHY the spaces are not getting removed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file does not have newlines like you expect.
The CLP will add trailing spaces to a much wider length than you might assume.

Separately, check if the data in file_path or filename columns contains a newline character, and strip them out via translate/replace in your query.

You can either postprocess the output file to remove spaces, or you can limit the width of the output string in SQL, or combine both approaches.

To remove the spaces in postprocessing:

`db2 -x "select trim(file_path || '/' || filename) from mytable" | sed 's/  //g' > $my_temp_file`

To limit the width of the output string in SQL (for example to 80 bytes, with the risk of truncation). This means that filenames shorter than 80 will be padded with spaces up to 80 (or however long you specify).

`db2 -x "select cast(rtrim(file_path || '/' || rtrim(filename) as varchar(80)) from mytable" > $my_temp_file`

Comment: Hi..thank you for answering but as you said 'postprocessing' Even if i am using the

command: sed -i '/^$/d' $my_temp_file 

OR

command: awk 'NF' $my_temp_file 

after the db2 command within the script, that's NOT working

Comment: The command that I put in my answer works for me, i don't use the -i  and I don't search for newline

Comment: okay. actually, I'll be deleting these records by reading this file one by one using loop, so therefore looking for a non-space file...btw thank you for your answer. Will try the same

Comment: Could you please tell me why we have 2 slashes before g in sed 's/ //g' ?

Comment: the expression asks to substitute two-consecutive-spaces by nothing (//), globally, i.e. to remove them